# Bash not responding after sudo pm2 log|app2 command, can only type

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sudo, pm2

please help as I can't seem to exit from 'forever typing mode' in my ubuntu server command line after typing the below command:

sudo pm2 log|app2

firstly it shows that command app2 is not found and then subsequently whatever I type, it just doesn't process, even CTRL+C. Whatever I typed will just be shown on command line like the picture below [image]. app2 is one of my process in pm2 but I guess it has to do with the wrongly '|' typed in between.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Posting information in screen shots is NOT recommended on SO, kindly post it in text format in CODE TAGS `{}` button.

Comment: Have you tried pressing `enter` and then `ctrl`+`D`?

Comment: @Socowi I tried, it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

At the end I just try the old school way: restarting the server and it's doing alright now. Thanks!